# Dependabot "update-type" not available in metadata retrieved for PR using dependabot/fetch-metadata@v1

Tags: github-actions, cicd

I'm trying to implement Dependabot automation using the docs:

https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/working-with-dependabot/automating-dependabot-with-github-actions

I want to approve Dependabot PRs, e.g. if they only include patch and minor dependency updates:

```
if: steps.dependabot-metadata.outputs.update-type == 'version-update:semver-patch' || steps.dependabot-metadata.outputs.update-type == 'version-update:semver-minor'
```

Now, the issue is that no information about `update-type` in the metadata retrieved from GitHub, which prevents the workflow from approving "safe" updates.

Why is `update-type` not available in the metadata, and how can I make it available to my workflow?

It's defined to be:

```
steps.dependabot-metadata.outputs.update-type
    The highest semver change being made by this PR, e.g. version-update:semver-major. For all possible values, see the ignore documentation.
```

https://github.com/dependabot/fetch-metadata/tree/v1.6.0

Example metadata about urllib3 (Python):

```
[{"dependencyName":"urllib3","dependencyType":"direct:production","updateType":"","directory":"/lego/master","packageEcosystem":"pip","targetBranch":"master","prevVersion":"","newVersion":"","compatScore":0,"maintainerChanges":false,"dependencyGroup":"","alertState":"","ghsaId":"","cvss":0}]
```

Dependabot workflow:

```
name: Dependabot
on:
  pull_request_target:
    types: [opened, reopened]

permissions:
  contents: write
  pull-requests: write

jobs:
  dependabot:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.actor == 'dependabot[bot]'
    steps:
      - name: Dependabot metadata
        id: dependabot-metadata
        uses: dependabot/fetch-metadata@v1
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Output updated dependencies (JSON)
        run: echo steps.dependabot-metadata.outputs.updated-dependencies-json
        env:
          PR_URL: ${{ github.event.pull_request.html_url }}
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Enable auto-merge for Dependabot PR
        #if: contains(steps.metadata.outputs.dependency-names, 'my-dependency') && steps.metadata.outputs.update-type == 'version-update:semver-patch'
        run: gh pr merge --auto --merge "$PR_URL"
        env:
          PR_URL: ${{ github.event.pull_request.html_url }}
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Approve patch and minor updates
        if: steps.dependabot-metadata.outputs.update-type == 'version-update:semver-patch' || steps.dependabot-metadata.outputs.update-type == 'version-update:semver-minor'
        run: gh pr review $PR_URL --approve -b "I'm **approving** this PR because **it includes patch or minor updates**"
        env:
          PR_URL: ${{ github.event.pull_request.html_url }}
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Approve major updates of development dependencies
        if: steps.dependabot-metadata.outputs.update-type == 'version-update:semver-major' && steps.dependabot-metadata.outputs.dependency-type == 'direct:development'
        run: gh pr review $PR_URL --approve -b "I'm **approving** this PR because **it includes a major update of a development dependency**"
        env:
          PR_URL: ${{ github.event.pull_request.html_url }}
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Comment on major updates of production dependencies
        if: steps.dependabot-metadata.outputs.update-type == 'version-update:semver-major' && steps.dependabot-metadata.outputs.dependency-type == 'direct:production'
        run: |
          gh pr comment $PR_URL --body "I'm **not approving** this PR because **it includes a major update of a production dependency**"
          gh pr edit $PR_URL --add-label "dependabot manual"
        env:
          PR_URL: ${{ github.event.pull_request.html_url }}
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: Sounds like [this bug](https://github.com/dependabot/fetch-metadata/issues/339).

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thank you. It's 9 months old, so they don't fix it?